woocommerce pagination. not working when sorting used
I build the child theme of the storefront parent theme.
shop page
When I chose sorting: Sort by price: low to high, the pagination is not working correctly.
first page: /shop/?orderby=price (browser link)
second page: /shop/page/2/  but should be  /shop/page/2/?orderby=price
I did a mistake in my child theme, but can't figure out what it is.

What is the code that prints the pagination?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
